# How to call an external webservice in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xml

I want to call an external webservice. How do I do this in an asp.net mvc program? What options do I have. Does anyone have an example?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the service exist already, or you are trying to create the service as well?

Comment: Is "Basic XML question" really a good summary of this question?

Comment: Yes, the service exists.

Comment: My fault, thought you meant you wanted to implement it in asp.net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call an external webservice in an ASP.NET MVC application the same way you call it in any .NET application. If it is a SOAP based service you generate a proxy class using [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx), if the service uses some proprietary XML you may need to resort to [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

check out [this article](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) if you're calling your web service client side using jQuery.

It's done with JSON, but you could get XML by changing the dataType parameter to dataType: "xml" or not including it all as it is the default.

If you're doing it server side check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx). It's VB.Net but you can easily translate it to C#

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I am looking for an mvc solution.